# Ringtone playing too long

Tags: java, android

I'm using a RingtoneManager with RingtonePreference. When I use the default Ringtone, there is no problem, but when i use a configured Ringtone, it's playing for minutes... I don't know if the song's duration is minutes or if it plays in a loop...

here my code:

```
private static void playNotificationSound(Context context) {
    RingtoneManager rm  = new RingtoneManager(context);
    String ringtone = MySharedPreferences.ringtone(context);
    Uri uri = null;
    if(ringtone == null)
        uri = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    else
        uri = Uri.parse(ringtone);
    if (uri != null) {
        Ringtone rt = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
        if (rt != null) {
            rt.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
            rt.play();
        }
    }
}
```

I use it to play a song with a notification and I don't want the phone to play for 5minutes...

Comment: whats the size of the ringtone?

Comment: I don't know the size. Its the ringtone in //media/internal/audio/media/33

Comment: But what's strange is that when I use uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION); the ringtone is played juste once.

Comment: There might be some problem with the format of the ringtone. I Guess .>!!
Compare the properties of both the default and other ringtone. You Might get some answer or way.

Comment: How can I compare their properties? :s

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following Line.

```
ringtoneManager.stopPreviousRingtone();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use thread like this?

```
if (rt != null) {
                rt.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

                rt.play();
            }

            Thread myThread = new Thread() {

                int wait = 0;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        super.run();

                        while (wait < 5000) {
                            sleep(500);
                            wait += 500;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    } finally {
                        if (rt.isPlaying())
                            rt.stop();

                    }
                }
            };
            myThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution, I set the notification.sound = uri; 
and don't use the RingtoneManager anymore.

with notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;

but the songs still plays in a loop. Maybe the ringtones really are 5minutes long? Or is it possible for a ringtone to be configured as a loop song?

Comment: Or is the solution to use MediaPlayer with setLoop(false)?

Comment: If your ringtone is small, and its running in loop for sure, you can use mPlayer.setLoop (false) effectively. It had worked for me

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I use mp.setDataSource(ringtone); mp.setLooping(false); mp.prepare() and mp.start(); The ringtone is played in loop...